# Windows Restart Manager's RmGetList returns ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED, why?

Tags: msdn, restartmanager

I have code that starts a [Restart Manager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc948910%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) session, then calls [RmRegisterResources](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa373663%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with a few files, and when it calls [RmGetList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa373661%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED (5) is returned... But if I add a Sleep for 50ms and then try again... It works... How come? Any idea? Is there anything else than sleep that could be done to successfully call RmGetList.

Comment: Hey man were you able to figure out why you needed that sleep? Sleep didn't fix it for me, but I'm also getting return value of 5.

Comment: I learned that I get `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED` when one or more of the registered resources refers to a *directory* instead of a *file*. (Sleeping obviously doesn't affect that, which is why this is a comment rather than an answer.)

Answer (score 2):

What do you exactly mean by "it works"? I tried on a file with an "access denied". The first call to RmGetList returned 5, arguments unchanged. Even without sleep in between the second call returned 0, while setting pnProcInfoNeeded, pnProcInfo and lpdwRebootReasons to zero. So you don't seem to get interesting info...

That looks like bug, or at least an undocumented feature.

Answer (score 0):

I have a inno setup installer, having a native call "rstrtmgr.dll". Fails every time installation but succeeds once or twice. phenomenon of access deny is similar as my case.
So I suggest my customer to reinstall everything in the slow computer.