# Inno Setup Installer "Rstrtmgr.dll" Access violation Happened

Tags: inno-setup, access-violation

I make Inno Setup Installer, run it and get the exception happened,
Message as following:

> Access violation at address 721DE701 in module 'Rstrtmgr.dll'.
> Read of address 2D6D2A70.

I think that `AlwaysRestart=yes` flag let installer access the `Rstrtmgr.dll`,
turn off `AlwaysRestart` flag, run again but the exception still happened.

What can i do?  Is any way not to access `Rstrtmgr.dll`?

- OS: Windows 7, Windows 10.
- Inno setup core version:  v5.6.1

---

I got the alike case: [Restart Manager Access Deny](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21617377/6923825).
My team try to install many times then Sometime one or two times installation is complete and no denied.
Behaviors are almost same as mine.

Comment: Windows 7 is officially end of life, so any efforts on that obsolete system can be in vain. Besides, access violation on a Windows core libraries is usually red flag on system integrity. You might have to reinstall Windows from its original installation media and try again, but why should you do that instead of upgrading to Windows 10 or 11?

Comment: And if you want our help anyway, we need [mcve].

Comment: 5.6.1 is pretty old version of Inno Setup. You need to upgrade. + Use of `Rstrtmgr.dll` is controlled by `CloseApplications` and `RestartApplications`, not `AlwaysRestart`.